# Проверка пароля

Tags: delphi

Вот написал скрипт

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  if edit1.Text='123' then
    PostMessage(FindWindow(Nil, 'Project1.exe'), WM_QUIT, 0, 0); 
  else 
    ShowMessage('Неверный пароль'); 
end;

end.
```

При создании программы пишет ошибку

> `';' not allowed before 'ELSE'`

Как сделать правильно? Мне нужно, чтобы запустилась программа. Я ввёл пароль '123', пароль оказался правильным - закрылась программа. Если пароль неправильный, то вылетает окошко об ошибки и пишет 'неправильный пароль'. Окошко должно выскочить повверх всех окон, т.к я прописал:

```
// Программа постоянно по вверх всех окон.
SetWindowPos(Form1.Handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Я нормально сформулиловал вопрос? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @LogDog, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Вы используете функции WinApi и не знаете, как пользоваться оператором условий?

Answer (score 4):

Delphi четко сообщил вам о проблеме

> ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'

Перед `else` никаких точек с запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Это не скрипт а программа уже :)

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if edit1.Text='123' then 
    Form1.Close //кажется так
  else 
    ShowMessage('Неверный пароль'); 
  end;
end.
```

Так будет правильнее синтаксически.

Comment: Так та всё верно, а как сделать, чтобы окно 'Неверный пароль' было поверх всех окон "

Comment: **ShowMessage** это модальное окно, и оно всегда должно быть выше всех.

Comment: Создаю программу, она всегда по вверх всех окон, ввожу неправельный пароль, окна не какого нет, и в поле ввода после набранного неправильного пароля больше ни чего нельзя написать, что делать ?

Comment: У вас Form1 - модальная форма?

Comment: >что делать?  
подключить фантазию и логическое мышление.

Создайте еще одну форму, разместите на ней сообщение, кнопку. И пропишите на ней:  
SetWindowPos(Form1.Handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE);

Comment: Да, а что ?

Comment: Попробую, а как узнать или создать модальную форму ?

Comment: Используйте MessageBox[Ex] вместо showmessage, с хэндлом вашей формы, будет поверх вашего окна.

Answer (score 0):

Как понял, вам надо, чтобы модальное окно было поверх всех остальных окон? Если да, то можно это сделать так:

```
// Включаем флаг "поверх всех окон"
setwindowpos(application.Handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,swp_nosize or swp_nomove or 
swp_noactivate);

showmessage('');

// Отключаем флаг "поверх всех окон"
setwindowpos(application.Handle,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,swp_nosize or swp_nomove or swp_noactivate);
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать, чтобы в шапки окошка было написано, например ошибка

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if edit1.Text='123' then 
    Form1.Close 
  else 
    ShowMessage('Неверный пароль'); 
  end;
end.

Comment: Спосибо всем огромное !!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите ответ =)